# "single largest" or "largest single"

Tags: phrases, word-order, phrase-usage

I commonly hear statements like "the largest single contributor to..." and "the single largest factor...". It seems as though "largest single" and "single largest" should have slightly different meanings, possibly that one would indicate a majority while the other a plurality, yet I can't find a clear answer. 
Please advise.

Comment: If there's only one exceptionally large factor, then the second may apply.  If there are a number of factors across a range of sizes, and the specified one is the largest, then the first would be more meaningful.  (Think about it:  What do you *mean*?)

Answer (score 4):

There is certainly a different meaning

### The largest single contributer

This is akin to

> The biggest solo contributor

### The single largest factor

This is akin to

> The biggest factor

In the latter expression, "single" is actually redundant because "largest" is a superlative.

In the former it is not, because we are specifically stating that the subject is singular - it does not include groups of contributors.

Note that the latter does have one case where "single" is *not* redundant: when there is a chance that there may be "joint winners"

It's quite a subtle difference, but there is a *slight* difference in connotation: one is implying solo vs groups (ie individuals or pressure groups donating to a political party), the other is implying outright vs joint winners (ie a clear winner as opposed joint first place in a race)

Comment: Correct.  In "the single largest factor", "single" is technically redundant, save for excluding the possibility of joint winners.  When used (by someone who understands the language) it's serves as an intensifier, basically making the phrase mean "the largest factor by far".

Answer (score -1):

Based on the examples you provided, it should probably be *single largest*, which is a set expression.

According to Longman DOCE 5th Ed.:

> the single biggest/greatest etc used to emphasize that you are talking about the one thing that is the biggest, greatest etc:
>   Tourism is the country’s single biggest earner.

"Largest single" is not incorrect (think "this is the largest single cell"), it just has a different meaning. But I cannot at the moment conceive of a sentence with "the largest single contributor to".

Therefore, *in your examples*, "the largest single contributor to" seems incorrect, although the full context could prove me wrong.

Comment: Incorrect, both phrases are correct and have subtly different meanings

Comment: I never claimed the former was incorrect, what I meant was that *in the provided examples* "the largest single contributor for" sounds odd and is probably just a mix-up. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: With all due respect to Longman, he can go take a flying leap.

Comment: @HotLicks Telling Longman what to do is hardly an argument. The info quoted from the entry is correct.

Comment: "The largest single factor" does not mean the same as "The single largest factor" - it's subtle, but it's definitely different. "The largest single factor" is emphasising that the factor in question and suggests more than a simple victory: ie the "victory" for that factor was by a large margin.

Comment: @JonStory no argument there, they *are* semantically different.